# Printing issues using javascript function to print in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

So I have a div with many rows in it then on a button click i try to print all of the rows out but for some reason i only get about 1/3 of them. This is the code that it is using.

```
    function buildPrint()
    {
        var sourceDiv = document.getElementById("display_div");
        document.getElementById("print_div").innerHTML = sourceDiv.innerHTML;
        window.print();
    }

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<div id="display_div">
<asp:CheckBox ID="showAllOptionals" runat="server" Text="Show All Optionals" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:Literal ID="mainTable" runat="server" />
</div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="PrintContent" runat="server">
<div id="print_div" style="page-break-after:always;">
</div>
```

Back end code:

```
<input onclick=\"buildPrint();\" id=\"printBtn\" type=\"button\" value=\"Print\">
```

Does anyone know why I cant have it print the entire full div??? I should also mention that it works fine in Chrome but IE is where I am having the issue.

Comment: Why do you copy the entire markup from one div to another? Wouldn't be better to have a print css to handle that?

Comment: In addition to what @mamoo has said, if you want to print the content of any specific element, try the jquery printElement plugin.

Comment: That would have been a smarter move here but this is just old existing code, do you think adding a print css would be the best?